# Countability(Mathematical analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

1) if $S$ is a countable subset of $R^2$,
show that for any two point $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2/S$ , there is a parallelogram in $\mathbb R^2/S$ having $x,y$ as opposite vertices.
Here parallelogram means only the 4 edges(including $4$ vertices,but not including any interior point.)

i have no idea for this question,plz help!!

Comment: What have you already tried? For instance, do you see how to proceed if $S$ is actually finite?

Comment: Also, it might help to think about what's left to be specified in the parallelogram once you've specified two opposite vertices. If you think about it, you should find that you can actually pick the slope of the line segments through the two opposite vertices to be whatever you want. You'll need this fact.

Comment: Is it I need to prove that there exits line segments belongs to R^2\S ?

Comment: Yes, I like Ian's idea. If you consider the set of all line segments from, say, $x$, will some of them completely avoid the countable set $S$?

Comment: I think R^2\S is uncountable , since R^2=RXR , R^2 is uncountable by Product theorem, then move out some countable set from the uncountable set , so R^2\S uncountable . Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE! Please try to include your work in your questions. If you have any doubts, please check out the "help" linked at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint/partial proof**: Consider the point $x$.  You want to draw an edge so that it misses all of the points of your countable set $S$ that you are trying to avoid.

How many directions can that edge go?  (think of direction as angle and realize that the angle can be anywhere in the continuum from $[0,2\pi)$).

How many of those directions could have been bad directions to go?

Look at all of the "good directions" for $x$, and move over to $y$ instead.  How many of the good directions for $x$ will be bad directions for $y$?

So, you have a line leaving $x$ and another line leaving $y$ going parallel.  Can you repeat this process again?  What shape does this make?

Comment: I think it can be all direction because there exists another point belongs to R^2\S. The direction that approach to the integer is bad because QxQ is not belongs to R^2\S.but I stiil not know what I need to write in this question

Comment: @soho19941018 Who said anything about $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$?  Yes, this proof will still work if $S=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, but maybe $S$ was something different or stranger (or simpler) than that.  The essence is that there are *uncountably many* directions you could go, and only *countably many* of them are "bad."  Thus, there are *uncountably many good* directions to go.  It is not *all* directions (there will be potentially infinitely many bad directions, but only countably many since $S$ is countable).